# S57 Ecdis extract data

Tags: java, netcdf, s-57

I have multiple S57 Ecdis files and would like to extract some data out of them. In specific some 'depth' data which is bound to lat/lon coordinates.
I will need to bulk process all the data and group them based of their locations. Basically we have a map where polygons are drawn on and for each polygon we need to calculate the min/max/median of all the depth-values that are inside it.

- Do you have any recommendations on how to do this?
- Would it be possible to convert it to NetCDF file or to some kind of raster?

The program will be written in Java so preferably I’d like to convert it using some Java libs.